# What is the difference between "I don't know when it starts" and " I don't know when it does start" in this context

Tags: grammar

If someone asks me "when does school start again" and if I don´t know the answer should I say:

> 1 I don't know when it starts.
>
> or
>
> 2 I don't know when it does start.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely unlikely in the specific cited context, but *in general*, this kind of "do-support" is used to convey ***emphasis*** (particularly, emphatic ***refutation*** of a claim made or implied by someone else). In ***speech***, the word ***do*** (or ***does, don't,*** etc.) usually carries heavy stress, which also reflects that emphasis.

Thus *I **do** love you* could either occur as a response to your distrustful partner having said *I don't believe you love me*, OR it could be a spontaneous declaration of extreme affection *(I **really** love you very much indeed!)*.

I can just about imagine a native speaker coming out with OP's version #2 if the intended meaning is to emphasise that maybe school ***won't*** start again. But more likely that would be expressed as...

> *I don't know **if it will** [ever] start again*

Comment: But what if I want to say that I don´t know when it will start knowing that it will start soon?